# Boot a LiveCD and run another disk's Linux installer

Tags: system-installation, debian-installer

I have an old computer in which I'm trying to install Debian. It doesn't have a CD burner, but I managed to boot an Ubuntu 8.10 LiveCD there.

I have an 8GB USB stick available, but the computer won't boot from the USB key. I can download anything to the USB key, though, so I was wondering - **can I run a Debian installer from the USB key by first booting into the Ubuntu LiveCD?**

I know the easy way is to get a Debian CD from anywhere else.

I've also read about `debootstrap`, but it seems you have to manually do lots of stuff to get it working - ie, you don't run a Debian installer, you build Debian from scratch.

Is there any alternative?

Comment: Is the computer incapable of booting from USB, or has it just been unsuccessful up until now?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick the computer offers to boot from USB, but I've tried the same USB stick on a different computer and it works there but not on this machine. So I assume it can't really boot from there - it may be broken since I bought it ten years ago.